# Getting the velocity of a pan without a pan gesture

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, uitouch

I'm writing a UIView subclass that uses the `-touches{Began,Moved,Ended,Cancelled}:withEvent:` method to track dragging and tapping. (I'm not using a pan gesture recognizer because it doesn't recognize just a tap, and I don't use a tap plus a pan recognizer because they don't seem to move through phases in the same way. Believe me, I've tried it two or three times already.) At the end of a drag, I'd like to check the velocity and make a small tweak to the operation I'm performing if their finger left the screen while it was still moving.

The problem is, I'm getting some strange behavior from my velocity calculating code. My touch-handling methods all end up calling this simple velocity-calculating method:

```
- (void)updateDraggingVelocityWithTouch:(UITouch*)touch {
    NSTimeInterval timespan = touch.timestamp - self.lastDraggingTimestamp;

    CGPoint pt = [touch locationInView:self];

    CGPoint v;
    v.x = (pt.x - self.lastDraggingLocation.x)/timespan;
    v.y = (pt.y - self.lastDraggingLocation.y)/timespan;
    self.draggingVelocity = v;

    NSLog(@"Velocity: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(v));

    self.lastDraggingLocation = pt;
    self.lastDraggingTimestamp = touch.timestamp;
}
```

For some reason, though, this seems to calculate anomalously high velocities at the end of the pan, exactly when I want to know the velocity. For instance:

```
2012-11-10 20:38:02.603 Alef[32850:907] Velocity: {0, 0}
2012-11-10 20:38:02.747 Alef[32850:907] Velocity: {-8.35417, 5.0125}
2012-11-10 20:38:02.763 Alef[32850:907] Velocity: {-30.2068, 0}
2012-11-10 20:38:02.780 Alef[32850:907] Velocity: {-29.7612, 0}
2012-11-10 20:38:02.796 Alef[32850:907] Velocity: {-30.2924, 0}
2012-11-10 20:38:02.863 Alef[32850:907] Velocity: {-7.48297, 0}
2012-11-10 20:38:02.930 Alef[32850:907] Velocity: {-7.526, 0}
2012-11-10 20:38:03.030 Alef[32850:907] Velocity: {-4.99497, 0}
2012-11-10 20:38:03.432 Alef[32850:907] Velocity: {-40.5009, 40.5009}
```

Sometimes it's even higher—I've seen ending velocities over 100 on swipes that otherwise never reached 15.

Any idea why this might happen? Should I be using a different algorithm than the simple difference one I've shown here?

Comment: I noticed that on some (rather all) devices, moving outside a region can cause some kind of maximum distance swipe to come into play.  Have you considered creating a restraint on your app's uptake of the input to null unusual behavior like this?  For example, code it to ignore anything greater than 15?  Like `if (self.draggingVelocity > 15) {v=null;} else { v=self.draggingVelocity; }`.  In other words, are there unusual events occurring below the maximum velocity, also?

Comment: When I also log the point and timestamp, the point doesn't look unusual, but I did notice that the timestamp is much closer to the previous one than usual. That would magnify the apparent velocity of the touch. Perhaps I just have to skip updating the velocity from the ending touch--but then I'm throwing away my most recent data...

Comment: Is it possible that the screen is murky, and the connection between the user's finger and the screen is skipping as they drag their finger? ^o^